# Assumptions in the bound on chaos

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, quantum-information, qft-in-curved-spacetime, chaos-theory

In the paper [A bound on chaos](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.01409), by Maldacena, Shenker and Stanford. They mention two assumptions to prove that the Lyapunov exponent in the OTOCs must be smaller than or equal to $2\pi T$.

One of the assumptions is that there is a "large hierarchy between scrambling and dissipation". By this "hierarchy", do they mean that dissipation occurs way before scrambling does?